# Interactive push Notification ios8

Tags: iphone, ios8, push-notification

Is there any way to change the background color of custom action button for Interactive push notification in ios8?
Default color of button background is Gray and Blue
I want to change it to Green and Orange, any idea?
Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Actually I am not getting any property to set backgound color for custom button for interactive push notification.